# Android 6.0 (M) skip Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS with admin

Tags: android, admin, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

Is it possible to avoid runtime permission with admin permission?

I have to change something in Settings.System, but unfortunately on Android M, I have to ask user to allow me...

Comment: There is no way to avoid permissions in 6.0 . In Android 6.0 Marshmallow, application will not be granted any permission at installation time. Instead, application has to ask user for a permission one-by-one at run-time.

Comment: @Lau you have to ask runtime for Android 6.0. For more understanding refer this http://coderzpassion.com/android-new-runtime-permissions/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Permission of WRITE_SETTINGS has been revoked from user apps (as in not system apps) in api23. From looking into source code in android we can see the following protection levels for this permission:

```
 <permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    android:label="@string/permlab_writeSettings"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_writeSettings"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|preinstalled|appop|pre23" />
```

which means you can gain this permission by either:
1.Targetting sdk lower then 23 in your manifest
2. By having system signature, by having app preinstalled in system (/app or /priv-app) or by gaining permission through appop (not relevant).

So, as user app targeting sdk23 you cannot gain this permission. Target sdk 22 and lower for gaining this permission from manifest. it works fine.

Comment: 1) No chances to lower sdk
2) What does it means?
3) Is it even possible?

Comment: 1. No chances to lower sdk? Why? Didn't know it was a Catholic marriage... 2. It means installed in system. Which you will not do. Since you don't even know what it means. 3. No. It's irrelevant as I mentioned. You need to either lower target sdk or you will never get this permission on api23. Not even if requested on runtime.